# "USB computer connection" keeps appearing & Chrome inspect appearing/disappearing when debugging cordova app

Tags: android, cordova, google-chrome

Using new 4.4.2 ZTE T230 Android phone with no SIM card. "USB computer connection" keeps popping up on the phone when I'm trying to debug a cordova app. I've tried selecting MTP, PTP, etc, and pressing the bottom center button but it keeps on reappearing. I tried unplugging it and turning USB debugging on and off. It shows up normally in "adb devices" (Mac OSX) but in Chrome inspect devices it keeps on disappearing and reappearing by itself.
Sometimes the problem temporarily goes away then comes back.
In Chrome it says: (Version/4.0 Chrome/30.0.0.0)

A Huawei phone shows up fine for Chrome inspect devices (says 33.0.0.0). To get it working with Mac OSX adb I had to do

`adb forward tcp:9222 localabstract:chrome_devtools_remote`

I switched the phones over so no longer need to get the ZTE phone working.

Comment: its look like hardware problem. your usb cable or phone usb input or pc usb not working wery well. I had this problem. my usb cable is not original one. I  replaced good one .problem resolved.